# Usuarios git Ubuntu Server

Tags: git, ubuntu, servidor, git-push

He montado un servidor ubuntu server, he creado usuarios ss, y todos pueden clonar los repositorios. Sin embargo solo el usuario administrador puede hacer commit. He creado mas usuarios admin y aun así no he logrado que puedan realizar commit con otra cuenta, solo con la que registre al levantar el servidor.

¿Que falta hacer? ¿Donde hay que dar permisos?

Comment: podrias dar un git status con uno de esos usuarios para ver que te aparece

Answer (score 1):

Tengo una teoría, creo que es porque si usaste el usuario administrador para instalar GIT en la maquina, las configuraciones las debe estar tomando de ~/.gitconfig donde esta el usuario que hace el commit, puede ser que los otros usuarios no tengan creado este archivo? y por ende no puedan realizar procesos en el repo?

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Estoy asumiendo que se quiere hacer commit solo sobre la rama en local y no subirlo a donde este alojado, porque si es así tienes que realizar la autenticación de usuarios vía ssh (clave privada y pública) o vía https con usuario y password.

Saludos,